# Feature request: Create a separate site for feature requests

Tags: feature-request

The prominently displayed feature request tag on this site should be removed immediately.

A Q&A site does NOT mix well with feature requests.

A Q&A site correctly punishes duplicate questions because duplicate questions lower the quality of the site.

But this mindset of seeking to shoot down duplicates is exactly the opposite of what is needed for consideration of feature requests.

The latter is best served by an open and creative mindset that will consider the feature request on its own merits with intent of actually hearing the unmet need rather than seeking to punish the person providing feedback.

Including the feature request tag on meta is a mistake.

People who express their unmet needs via feature requests are likely to be punished for doing so by the duplicate eradication mindset.

This punishing of good behavior harms Stack Exchange in 2 ways.

1. It creates a strong negative experience of the person reporting their unmet need.
2. It robs Stack Exchange of the feedback it needs to keep innovating to better meet the needs of users.

Comment: Related: [Will Meta Stack Exchange be removed now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339051/289905). _“the duplicate eradication mindset”_ — Again, edit your post to explicitly explain why your post is not a duplicate. See [Someone flagged my question as already answered, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194476/289905). I’ve already explained that question closure isn’t rude behavior in your previous question post. Again, make sure to familiarize yourself with the site rules before calling everything “negative experience”, “punishing”, or “a mistake”.

Comment: @Alex I disagree with _this_ feature request and I've downvoted it but you are indeed right that this isn't the same feature request that you posted twice already. It should be treated as a separate issue.

Comment: Care to explain why you disagree with the feature request?

Comment: I agree that we shouldn't _always_ close duplicate feature requests as duplicates. Old declined FKs, for example, should be revisited from time to time. I do disagree, however, that a Q&A format _cannot_ work for feature requests. If you a quick search here, you'll find great feature requests that got implemented at some point. You will also find great (and highly upvoted) feature requests that got declined by staff. Finally, please note that votes on meta work differently compared to those on main sites. Votes on meta (especially on FKs) indicate that someone does (or doesn't) support the FK.

Comment: Not everyone that posts a feature request gets "punished". But when posting one, you should accept that not everyone is going to agree with your viewpoint. Sometimes, the majority of users/voters will agree with you. Some other times, they won't. The fact that the FK is presented in a Q&A format (which is admittedly not perfect on Meta) is somewhat irrelevant in this context. That's just my opinion, of course.

Comment: I just noticed that I typed FK instead of FR (four times). I feel stupid! I've been spending too much time with databases recently, I guess.

Comment: You are correct that a Q&A platform used for meta purposes (e.g., feature requests) is a bad fit. Unfortunately, it will probably never be changed (it reflects the low emphasis the founders put on it, and this culture has unfortunately been carried forward). It will take another company and another (new) platform to do it.

Answer (score 6):

We have a site for feature requests. Meta is it.

In the past - and I mean the distant past, we used to use uservoice for feature requests, but folks found meta to be more accessible.

After fighting to save meta, I'm unsure why there would be any real support for hiving off one of its core functions.