# Shog9 and Robert Cartaino are still listed as moderators in Area 51 Discussion

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, area-51, moderators

Based on the posts [Thank you, Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342031/312043) and [Thank You, Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342079/312043), they no longer work for Stack Exchange, and their moderator access was revoked from all the Stack Exchange sites.

However, when I see the [Area 51 Discussion Zone Moderators page](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), their accounts are still listed as moderators.

> [image: Area 51 Discussion Zone Moderators page]

But when I checked their Area 51 main accounts ([Shog9](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/125/shog9), [Robert Cartaino](https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/5/robert-cartaino)), the moderator access is removed as well as in their Network Profiles ([Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9?tab=accounts), [Robert Cartaino](https://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino?tab=accounts)).

So it seems to be a bug to me, or is this a special case for Area 51 discussion only?

If not, can the information about the user's moderation be updated in Area 51 Discussion Zone too?

Comment: Area51 is now a zombie site, with no active moderation.

Comment: @ShadowTheBurningWizard Yes. Given how active Robert was there and the lack of replacement, I strongly suspect Area51 just got killed.

Comment: This is not a new issue. This has happened before with several other former staff members.

Comment: Considering the rumours I keep hearing about the financial situation of SE, it might not be a bad thing if Area51 closes down for a while. Sure, it's sour, but better than the whole of SE going upside down. Of-course it's handled poorly, but that's another matter.

Comment: Attempting to join area 51 gives me a login error

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should now be fixed; if it doesn't show immediately: the cache is sentimental .

Comment: Can you define 'fix' for me? Seems like removing their names is the exact opposite of an improvement.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs why? if they're no longer performing that role, why would they be listed?

Comment: It was sarcasm. I am saying that them leaving the site is unfortunate

Comment: It happened again, now there are 3 former employees showing up this time. It's a common issue. (The Stack Exchange team seem to have forgotten how to get to Area 51.)

Comment: This is not a fix for the bug.