# Former(?) staff member still listed as moderator on Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, moderators, stack-exchange-team

It seems [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/274323/nicolas-chabanovsky) left the company? I am not sure if there will be an [announcement like this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388800/295232) – if not, спасибо Nicholas for all the work you've done!

Let me honor you with a bug report: you're still listed as a [moderator on Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/48390/nicolas-chabanovsky). This looks like [another hiccup of the account provisioning system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342100/295232).

Comment: :( .............

Comment: On https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/48390/nicolas-chabanovsky, there are no diamonds, but on https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41168/stack-overflow-in-russian his display name is followed by a diamond.

Comment: For once, Mastodon has news: ["Unlike the other dozen+ plus layoffs I've been through in my career, I didn't see this one coming."](https://hachyderm.io/@wrightfully/110344694801673550) I don't know if Nicolas was one of the people laid off, but it looks like Stack Overflow cut staff today. :-(

Comment: See also [Today's actions by Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389060/todays-actions-by-stack-overflow) / [A Message from Prashanth Chandrasekar, CEO Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/10/a-message-from-prashanth-chandrasekar-ceo-stack-overflow/)

Comment: [Another one](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/216329/salmon-of-wisdom)? :/

Comment: @JonEricson it's a trend. No other real reason I can see. They have backup of billions now, but.... really not into business so can't really judge, just rant.