# When picking articles for the company blog, can we please try to avoid posts that can be negatively tied to recent events?

Tags: discussion, blog

Recently Stack Exchange found itself at the center of two new "incidents".

- [Today's actions by Stack Overflow (May 10, 2023)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389060/todays-actions-by-stack-overflow-may-10-2023/389081#389081): Stack Overflow disclosed the reduction of its workforce by 58 people, or about 10% of their total staff.
- [Is SE [going to be] selling our content for AI model training? And what exactly does "reinvest back into our communities" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388551/is-se-going-to-be-selling-our-content-for-ai-model-training-and-what-exactly/388612#388612): a user posted some concerns about an article on Wired that referenced Stack Exchange intention to "Charge AI Giants for Training Data".

I am not discussing those here again, please follow the links if you are interested in further info.

I just wanted to point out that today by sheer chance I saw a link to the blog posted in the Tavern chatroom. Usually I ignore those but in the light of the previously mentioned events the clickbait title ["The AI is the UI"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/12/the-overflow-177-the-ai-is-the-ui/) caught my attention so I skimmed over it.

And I noticed two posts that I would probably have avoided ***now***.

- How to land a job in climate tech: telling people how to find a job...
- When AI meets IP: Can artists sue AI imitators? (Ep. 566) : an article about the question if the creators of some content can sue someone for training an AI with said content.

Alone these two article would just pass over my head. A problem arises when you tell people how to find a job right after firing 58 employees, or tell content creators that "Fair use" means AI training is legal after they discovered that their post will be sold for that very reason.

I am willing to think this is just an unfortunate coincidence with no ill intent. But it is still a VERY unfortunate coincidence. I would therefore kindly request that articles picked for the blog would be checked to see if they could feel problematic at the time of posting.

Comment: It's Fate telling Stack Exchange: "**nah!**".

Comment: Also, it just shows how cold hearted machines are, and AI among them, no better even a tiny bit. And into that Darkness SE goes heads on, intentionally, to mine some dirty coins.

Comment: I literally feel like the one on careers in sustainability was one written for SO careers, uploaded to make up numbers, then had a SOFT promo tacked on at the end.

Comment: What about the timing? Why would the blog folks know about the firings in advance? They are not all-knowing. The lead time for the blog posts may be many weeks (even many months) and may just as well be related to [the Big Tech firings](https://www.wired.com/story/google-meta-big-tech-is-bad-at-firing/) (and trickle down into smaller companies). Are you asking for the blog posts to be taken down?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Well, even if what you suggested was true (I suspect that they knew in advance and that the blog is not "pre-made" so in advance) the "release" date for that post is May, 12th - after the two incidents. They could use a "go-live" final review, or they could actually remove said problematic posts.