# A staff member that's a moderator network-wide is visible in the Moderators list

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderators, users-page

The staff member [m0sa](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/156631/m0sa) is listed in the [moderators tab in the users page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) as though they are an elected or appointed moderator. This issue is present all across the network, no matter which site you visit. This is likely a result of them no longer having Staff status on their profile.

I *hope* this doesn't mean that they've left the company. If that is the case... That's tough to hear. m0sa's been around for [quite awhile](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/25/summer-hiring-happened-so-fast/).

In any case, could this be fixed?

Comment: _In any case, could this be fixed?_ The fix here being giving the Staff status back, hopefully :\

Comment: Well sadly enough, most likely the missing staff label means he's no longer staff. As far as I know, when a developer is laid off it is instant: everything is done right away, as security measure to prevent any chance of "rage quit". (I mean the case when it's not done in consent i.e. "kicked out".)

Comment: And... hate to be right here, but it's now clear he's no longer working for SE, no diamonds anymore.

Comment: [Jon Chan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043674/jon-chan) is also no longer Staff, and briefly appeared as a moderator I guess soon after their Staff status was removed

Comment: ...not my fault

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[UPDATE]** - Thanks again for flagging this. The team found the issue and fixed the account, so it should be all set now.

Thanks for flagging. We're looking into it. I'll post back here (early next week) once this has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, no matter how sad it is to see a veteran face leave. You may want to double check [their Area 51 profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), as they're still listed as a moderator there. This has [historically been a pesky site for network-wide mod status removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389054/).

Comment: Looks like it's resolved already, no diamonds anymore for that user, and he's not listed in the moderators tab of the users page. Was it some stubborn server side cache that got cleared by itself?