# Featured tag question stopped listing in the "Featured on Meta" section of side bar

Tags: support, sidebar, featured-tag

Why all of a sudden, [Thank you, Robert Cartaino](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342079) is stopped listing in the "Featured on Meta" section of side bar in all of the Stack Exchange sites.

There are only two questions with the [featured tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured) in MSE currently, and "Thank you, Shog9" is listed in the side bar and not the "Thank you, Robert Cartaino" post.

Up to few minutes before, both the featured tag questions are listed in the side bar.

[image]

Is it a bug?

Comment: Probably just caching. It isn't updated immediately.

Comment: @curiousdannii For 2 hours?

Comment: It used to be there for a little while, like PPP said. I saw it too. I'm not sure, this thing has always had issues with caching too, but this seems more like it's broken.

Comment: Featured could be cached for days. At least, on ruSO)

Comment: It seems to be back here :)

Comment: So, it was probably cached after all.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be back in the side bar section of "Featured on Meta".

[image: side bar]