# Does the Stack Exchange network claim to have a site for every possible topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, scope

I wonder if network has a site for everything.

Or are there topics which are not covered by stackexchange?

Comment: No, it does not. See [this](https://stackexchange.com/sites).

Comment: I know this site. Seems there is a site for everything. But I'm not sure...

Comment: For example: There does not seem to be a site dedicated to Q&A about learning the Thai language. Thus, there is not a site for every possible topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, it does not.

There is (or, at least, was) a process for new Stack Exchange sites to be created, using a site called Area 51.

One of the main people in charge of Area 51 [was fired earlier this week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342079/348149), so whether things will change moving forward hasn't yet been clarified, but in general, it is safe to say that there is not a SE site for every topic.

Rather, there is a SE site for every topic that a SE site has been created for.